# about algorithm in image processing for face recognition and face detection

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, face-detection, face-recognition

what is the technique or algorithm that i can use for face detection and face recognition for a college project. Can i use any algorithm which uses 3d rather than 2d?

Comment: Generally the fact that there are several companies with entire teams devoted to this who have not produced satisfactory solutions is a clue that this question may be overly broad.  If you're interested in the area of image recognition I recommend studying Probabilistic Graphical Models.

Comment: How about searching web or reading a book about the subject? Seriously, it will help you in depth.

Comment: I agree with airza. You can have a look to [Ada Boost](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) to read an exemple.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV provides an [object detection](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/objdetect.html) module which can be used for face recognition.

Comment: Thanks guys. Thanks a lot. I will do the readings

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you go for ML techniques like **[Fisher's linear discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis)** and **[Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)** for face detection as well as classification.